# React Google Login

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I am using *react-google-login* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) tool to login to provide Google login functionality for my application. Following the manual on page I ended up using following code.

```
<GoogleLogin
   clientId="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
   onSuccess={this.responseGoogle.bind(this)}
   onFailure={this.responseGoogle.bind(this)}
   tag={'span'}
   className={"google-button-wrapper"}
   >
   <Button id={'google-button'} basic
      color='google plus'>
      <Icon name='google plus'/>
      Google Plus
   </Button>
</GoogleLogin>
```

The problem is that the login action is triggered even without clicking the button. This happens after refresh page.

I found following suspicious scenarios:

> Refresh page -> open Login page = Triggered
>
> Refresh page -> open Login page -> Open different site -> Login again = Triggered first time, second time no trigger.
>
> Refresh page -> open Login page -> open Registration Page = Trigger on Login page, not trigger on Register page even if there is same snipped of code.

I am using React v ^16.3.2,
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use arrow functions inside onSuccess and onFailure and don't bind them here. It is better practice to bind functions on constructor

Comment: Can i get an explanation why was my answer downvoted?

Comment: I channged code to the following:  onSuccess={() => this.responseGoogle} .. etc. It helped. I wonder why it is causing problems only here and not on the other function bindings. Thank you. I must check the docs

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem

```
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';


const CLIENT_ID = '<client_id>';


class GoogleBtn extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLogined: false,
      accessToken: ''
    };

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleLoginFailure = this.handleLoginFailure.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutFailure = this.handleLogoutFailure.bind(this);
  }

  login (response) {
    if(response.accessToken){
      this.setState(state => ({
        isLogined: true,
        accessToken: response.accessToken
      }));
    }
  }

  logout (response) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isLogined: false,
      accessToken: ''
    }));
  }

  handleLoginFailure (response) {
    alert('Failed to log in')
  }

  handleLogoutFailure (response) {
    alert('Failed to log out')
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      { this.state.isLogined ?
        <GoogleLogout
          clientId={ CLIENT_ID }
          buttonText='Logout'
          onLogoutSuccess={ this.logout }
          onFailure={ this.handleLogoutFailure }
          render={renderProps => (
            <Button onClick={renderProps.onClick} size="small">Logout</Button>)}
        />
           : <GoogleLogin
          clientId={ CLIENT_ID }
          buttonText='Login'
          onSuccess={ this.login }
          onFailure={ this.handleLoginFailure }
          cookiePolicy={ 'single_host_origin' }
          responseType='code,token'
          render={renderProps => (
            <Button onClick={renderProps.onClick}size="small">Login</Button>)}
        />
      }
      

    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out, if you login once and then refresh the page without logging out, the login action is triggered without even clicking the button because the login state is preserved.

Try logging out and then refreshing the page.