# How to make <GoogleLogin /> from react-google-login inherit <App />'s this

Tags: reactjs

On the line:

```
onSuccess={() => this.responseGoogle}
```

How do I change **this** from being undefined (so that react-google-login works)?

```
    import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';

    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
      var profile = response["profileObj"];
      var email = profile["email"];
      if (email.includes('@domain.com')) {
        this.setState({ permissions: 'internal' });
      } else {
        this.setState({ permissions: 'external' });
      }
    }

  class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { permissions: 'none' };
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <GoogleLogin
           clientID = secret
           buttonText = "Log In with Google!"
           theme = "dark"
           cookiePolicy = {'single_host_origin'}
           onSuccess = {() => this.responseGoogle}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```

Exact same question as [React Google Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984016/react-google-login) and  [Trouble accessing props in callback function of Google Login using react-google-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291806/trouble-accessing-props-in-callback-function-of-google-login-using-react-google). Responses to those questions don't solve the issue (**this** still undefined).

Thank you very much for your thoughts!!

Comment: Your snippet is wrong. Can you share the exact code that's causing the error?

Comment: @DanLupascu apologies -- found the error and added more detail.  The exact error code is onSuccess = {() => this.responseGoogle}.  Specifically, **this** does not bind to this.state, despite the arrow function.  Rather, **this** remains undefined, causing **this.setState** to fail.  Thank you very much for your thoughts.

Comment: Can you share the exact code? In your snippet, the responseGoogle function is outside the Home component, why?